# Ubuntu20 rename window, search window is controlled by which process

Tags: gnome, nautilus, kde

I'd like to ask you some questions.The following two Windows are opened by what process.Rename Windows and the interface for searching information.

thanks!

[image: Rename Windows]

[image: the interface for searching information]

Comment: It's part of `gnome-shell` I'd guess, but why d'you ask?

Comment: Because the project needs to hook(prehook) the behavior of the other software, controlling the copying and pasting of text.But in both cases Hook failed.

Comment: The "gnome-shell" process does not load the dynamic libraries written in the file "/etc/ld.so.preload"